# Deploying an N-Layered ASP.NET Webforms Application In A Shared Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, webforms

I Have a solution that containts 4 layers (3 Class Libraries and 1 Web Application). I Need to deploy this solution to my shared hosting account. I've read a little about deployment and I hope I could perform a 'Precompiled Deployment' because as far as I know, It gives a better experience for the first time users as it's already compliled.

I don't see the "Publish Application" or whatever under the 'Build' menu, I setuped Microsoft Website Copy Tool. and I have on my shared account the Deployment Tool. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

..Any one can help with details to deploy my first website on the internet !? :)

Comment: What version of VisualStudio are you using?

Comment: My Bad =D, It's VS 2010 Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your web application the solution explorer. Select 'publish' from there or is it disabled?

Comment: I found it and it worked and my application is published .. but when I can't see the files on the IIS 7 Manager but I can see them from my File Manager. any page that I try to access gives me 404 or 500 error!